# Having trouble with Terraform and AWS Storage Gateway disks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform with AWS and have been able to create an AWS Storage Gateway file gateway using the aws_storagegateway_gateway resource.

The gateway will create and the status will be 'online' however there is not a cache disk added yet in the console which is normal as it has to be done after the gateway is created. The VM does have a disk and it is available to add in the console and doing so in the console works perfectly.

However, I am trying to add the disk with Terraform once the gateway is created and cannot seem to get the code to work, or quite possibly don't understand how to get it to work.

Trying to use the aws_storagegateway_cache resource but I get an error on the disk_id and do not know how to get it to return from the code of the gateway creation.

Might someone have a working example of how to get the cache disk to add with Terraform once the gateway is created or know how to get the disk_id so I can add it?

Adding code

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access-key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret-key}"
  token      = "${var.token}"
  region     = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_gateway" "hmsgw" {
  gateway_ip_address = "${var.gateway-ip-address}"
  gateway_name       = "${var.gateway-name}"
  gateway_timezone   = "${var.gateway-timezone}"
  gateway_type       = "${var.gateway-type}"

  smb_active_directory_settings {
    domain_name = "${var.domain-name}"
    username    = "${var.username}"
    password    = "${var.password}"
  }


}

resource "aws_storagegateway_cache" "sgwdisk" {
  disk_id     = "SCSI"
  gateway_arn = "${aws_storagegateway_gateway.hmsgw.arn}"
}

output "gatewayid" {
  value = "${aws_storagegateway_gateway.hmsgw.arn}"
}
```

The error I get is:

- aws_storagegateway_cache.sgwdisk: error adding Storage Gateway cache: InvalidGatewayRequestException: The specified disk does not exist.
      status code: 400, request id: fda602fd-a47e-11e8-a1f4-b383e2e2e2f6

I have attempted to hard code the disk_id like above or use a variable. On the variable I don't know if it is returned or exists so that could be the issue, new to this.

Comment: Can you share an [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, added code to original question. The last section of aws_storagegateway_cache is the one I cannot get to work.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you edit the question to include the exact output please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR added the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the AWS cli to run:  `aws storagegateway list-local-disks --gateway-arn [your gateway's arn] --region [gateway's region]`, you'll get data returned that includes the disk ID.

Then, in your example code, you replace `SCSI` with `"${gateway_arn}:[diskID from command above]"` and your cache volume will be created.

One thing I've noticed though - when I've done this and then tried to apply the same Terraform code again, and in some cases even with a targeted deploy of a specific resource within my Terraform, it wants to re-deploy the cache volume, because the Terraform is detecting that the disk ID is changing to a value of "1". Passing in "1" as the value in the Terraform, however, does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Before creating the resource "aws_storagegateway_cache", use data to get the disk id. I am using the below scripts and it works fine.

```
   variable "upload_disk_path" {
      default = "/dev/sdb"
    }

   data "aws_storagegateway_local_disk" "upload_disk" {
          disk_path   = "${var.upload_disk_path}"
          gateway_arn = "${aws_storagegateway_gateway.this.arn}"
        }

   resource "aws_storagegateway_upload_buffer" "stg_upload_buffer" {
          disk_id     = "${data.aws_storagegateway_local_disk.upload_disk.disk_id}"
          gateway_arn = "${aws_storagegateway_gateway.this.arn}"
        }
```

In case your are using two disk's (one for upload and one cahce), use the same code but set the default value of cache_disk_path = "/dev/sdc"

Comment: having been battling AwStGw for a while, this answer proved vital for the final bit of telling the StGw where to find its local storage, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would work also:

```
variable "disk_path" {
  default = "/dev/sdb"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "primary"
  access_key = var.access-key
  secret_key = var.secret-key
  token      = var.token
  region     = var.region
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_gateway" "hmsgw" {
  gateway_ip_address = var.gateway-ip-address
  gateway_name       = var.gateway-name
  gateway_timezone   = var.gateway-timezone
  gateway_type       = var.gateway-type

  smb_active_directory_settings {
    domain_name = var.domain-name
    username    = var.username
    password    = var.password
  }
}
 
data "aws_storagegateway_local_disk" "sgw_disk" {
  disk_path   = var.disk_path
  gateway_arn = aws_storagegateway_gateway.hmsgw.arn
  provider    = aws.primary
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_cache" "sgw_cache" {
  disk_id     = data.aws_storagegateway_local_disk.sgw_disk.id
  gateway_arn = aws_storagegateway_gateway.hmsgw.arn
  provider    = aws.primary
}
```